# Ignore or copy bitmap subtitles but convert to srt when possible with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's the ffmpeg command I currently use to re-encode videos in x265 :

`ffmpeg -i "${F}" -map 0 -map -v -map V -c:s srt -c:a aac -c:v hevc -preset medium "${bn}-x265.mkv"`

This is working well, except in the rare cases of bitmap subtitles :

`Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmap`

Is there an easy way to change my above command to either copy or ignore bitmap subtitles like this, but still convert to srt tracks that can be converted ?
Worse case I imagine I can just use `-c:s copy` but it seems a shame to miss an opportunity to convert to srt when possible.

Thanks

Comment: Need to see the complete log from the command that fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffprobe to see what codec each subtitle stream uses:

```
ffprobe -v error -of json input.mkv -of json -show_entries stream -select_streams s
```

There's a long list of codecs, so it's not a great idea to filter by codec. However, I noticed that image-based subtitle streams have a "width" attribute, while text-based ones don't. This can be used to filter image-based subtitles out, but it requires extra processing after running ffprobe.